# How to setup Dual Monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors

The specs of my PC are as follows:

- **CPU**: Intel Core i3-9100F 3.60GHz
- **GPU**: NVidia GT 1030 2GB
- **RAM**: 8GB
- **Motherboard**: Gigabyte

The main monitor has HDMI Port and the second one has VGA Port.

I am running single monitor for a long time but I thought it will be really cool if have a second one.

With all these specs, can I have dual monitor setup? If yes, how do I set it up?

Comment: I updated the drivers but still no luck.

Comment: How many video connectors are on your GT 1030 (on the graphics card itself, not on the PC motherboard) and what [type](https://www.diyaudioandvideo.com/TV/WireCableConversions/VideoConnectors.png) are they?  What brand (manufacturer) makes your GT 1030?

Comment: The manufacturer of GPU is Gigabyte and the type is HDMI. When I observed it, I found that the main monitor's HDMI cable goes straight into the GPU.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming the VGA cable is plugged into the motherboard video out? Also, is the HDMI out on the GPU the ONLY port on the card? I've seen a couple different Gigabyte GT 1030s and the most common one has an HDMI out and a DVI-D out, both are digital and not capable of sending an analog VGA signal . It may be possible to initialize the integrated GPU first and the add on card second, depending on the options on your motherboard's UEFI/BIOS firmware settings. Typically, you press F2 or DEL during boot to access the firmware. See what options you have for display settings there.

Comment: This [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wmIOuruxGfY) may be of some assistance.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Specifications of the
[GeForce GT 1030](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/graphics-cards/gt-1030/specifications/),
Multi Monitor is supported with combined maximal resolution of 7680x4320@60Hz.

The card can support DisplayPort 1.42 and HDMI 2.0b.

The rest depends on the number of the graphic ports that are available on your computer, and upon which cables are supported by your monitors.

Comment: I have a VGA Port for second monitor which I kept connected to the PC. I updated the NVidia drivers too but still no luck.

Comment: So you're connecting one monitor by VGA and the other by HDMI. What goes wrong? Please be precise.

Comment: There is just one port for HDMI and even the second monitor has VGA when I bought it. What happens is when I turn on the PC, both the monitors are connected to the power supply, the main one turns on but the second one lights up and says "No signal".

Comment: It's possible that your computer has two display adapters, one on-card and the other not. If the VGA is connected to the on-card one and the HDMI to the GeForce, then you cannot do multiple monitors. All ports in dual-display must belong to the same display adapter. Do you have a port for DisplayPort? What exact model is your computer (so we can get to the point)?

Comment: @harrymc, Some motherboards allow to initialize the internal GPU first and the add on GPU second, thereby allowing extended desktop across 2 GPUs.  However, duplication mode does not work in this configuration.  I don't know if OP's motherboard supports this configuration or not.

Answer (score -1):

For normal desktop work everything will be fine.

For video gaming on both monitors performance will be significantly worst because it driving 2x the number of pixels.

So the HDMI one will be very easy just plug the cable in and go.

You may need a VGA to DisplayPort or HDMI adapter as VGA ports are not very common any more.

-----update---------
Try this for drivers

https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/170312/en-us

Comment: Your link says temporarily off, maybe is a website issue

Comment: I agree about the gaming issue. But I believe he will solve it by buying an adapter for HDMI